# Crontab abrir página externa

Tags: php, email, iframe

Configurei um cron em meu servidor para executar um script php.

dentro do crontab executei a linha :

```
curl http://localhost/atualizacoes/check-atualizacoes.php
```

Ele executou perfeitamente, mas dentro desse php tenho um if que chama uma página externa, que envia um e-mail, tentei usando header, iframe e não conseguir fazer ele executar essa segunda pagina.

Se executo a pagina manualmente em meu browser funciona normalmente, alguém sabe me dizer o que preciso fazer?

Comment: Consegui o que queria com o seguinte comando no cron `/usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://localhost .....`